# Summon Item Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hello I'm trying to make a command where it summons a gold ingot. I tried this command but it says:

```
[19:31:10] Data tag parsing failed: Expected '}' but got ':' at: {Item:{id:minecraft:<--[HERE]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:gold_ingot,Count:1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing quotes on the id portion:`id:minecraft:gold_ingot`

When it is being parsed, it views the `:` in between `minecraft` and `gold_ingot` as command formatting.

Here is the command with the quotes:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:1}}
```

Comment: Wait, can you even summon items?

Comment: Yep.  I would not have posted it as an answer if you couldn't.